# I can not find this DFN-6 ic

Tags: identification

Can someone help me to identify this DFN-6 ic? It might be a boost converter. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The markings match with a [Texas Instruments TPS610981DSET](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps610981) boost converter.

[image]

The dimensions also match if the capacitors in the picture are 0603. However, you do not give a lot of information in your question, so make sure the pin out matches as well.